# Как разместить координатные оси по центру? (d3.js)

Tags: d3.js

Координатная сетка должна выглядить [так](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)

Код для создания динамической сетки [здесь](https://bl.ocks.org/evanjmg/ea3e59e67b4256c8831d3fc80f71294b)

Как сделать так, чтобы начальное положение осей x и y было по центру экрана, а при дальнейшем перетаскивании цифры появлялись бы сбоку (в тот момент, когда не видно главных осей)